# Does the polynomial belong to the ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, ideals

I need some help to really understand the ideals, that are generated by 2 or more polynomials in $\mathbb Q[x]$.

For example

> The ideal generated by the polynomials $1-x^3$ and $1+2x+2x^2+x^3$. Does the polynomial $x^3$ belong to this ideal?

I know that if $x^3 \in I$ it must $f(x) \cdot (1-x^3)+g(x) \cdot (1+2x+2x^2+x^3)=x^3$ But how do I know if there $\exists f(x),g(x)?$ and if so, how do I find $f(x),g(x)?$

Some dummy explanation will be very appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

*(Assuming you are working in $\mathbb{F}[x]$, with $\mathbb{F}$ a field)*

By definition of the $\gcd$, the ideal generated by $1-x^3$ and $1+2x+2x^2+x^3$ is the ideal generated by the $\gcd$ of these two polynomials. Here, you get that
$$\langle 1-x^3, 1+2x+2x^2+x^3\rangle=\langle x^2+x+1\rangle$$

The polynomial $x^3$ is clearly not a multiple of $x^2+x+1$, so it does not belong to the ideal generated by $1-x^3$ and $1+2x+2x^2+x^3$.

Comment: Why is the ideal generated by p, q, is the ideal generated by the gcd of p, q?

Comment: We should get it clarified whether or not the user is talking about $F[x]$ for a field $F$. That's likely, but not mentioned.  If it's $\mathbb Z[x]$ it might take more care to answer.

Comment: @Jack This is the definition of the $\gcd$ in a principal ring. The $\gcd$ of two elements $a$ and $b$ is the generator (unique up to a unit) of the ideal generated by the two elements.

Comment: @rschwieb You are right. I add this precision to my answer.

Comment: Oh yea im sorry, for my example I meant the ring $Q[x]$

Comment: I see. Thanks. I thought that the gcd is defined differently.

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: Where do you use a *field* $\mathbb{F}$ in the answer? In the last sentence?

Comment: @Jack If $\mathbb{A}$ is not a field, then $\mathbb{A}[x]$ is not principal, hence I cannot use the characterization of $\gcd$ I used.

Comment: Okay, I see. Thanks.